# Cómo detectar dentro del browser las opciones locales de puntuación para números y fechas

Tags: javascript, html5, navegador-web

¿Existe algo como `window.navigator.punctuation.numberSeparator == '.'`,  `window.navigator.punctuation.dateSeparator == '/'`?

Lo que necesito es una función que devuelva esos valores.

El problema de hacerlo a prueba y error (por ejemplo `toLocaleString()`) es que no queda claro cuál es el método para obtener de esa respuesta cuáles son los signos de puntuación. Las dificultades no son con los idiomas similares al castellano, uno podría obtener las partes con una expresión regular del tipo `/\d([^0-9]+)\d\d\d([^0-9]+)\d\d/` (utilizando como entrada `1234.5`).

El problema se complica porque no conozco todos los idiomas ni las posibles formas. ¿qué pasa con los números negativos? el signo puede estar delante o atrás del número, ¿podría ocurrir en alguna región que los números empiecen siempre con un espacio o signo adicional?.

```js
function obtenerSeparadoresNumero(){
    var matches=parseFloat(1234.56)
        .toLocaleString()
        .match(/1(\D+)234(\D+)56/);
    return {
        separadorMiles:matches[1],
        separadorDecimal:matches[2]
    };
}

console.log(obtenerSeparadoresNumero());
```

En ese ejemplo solo se obtiene el separador decimal y de miles, no la forma y lugar del signo de números negativos y no está probado para una buena cantidad de idiomas.

Mi pregunta es si existe algo que sirva para una buena cantidad de regiones.

Comment: Tu problema no es turing computable, y en general, especifica a ciertas regiones. Me atrevería a decir que es un error de análisis, no hace falta saber el formato para representar fechas o números, puesto que el navegador es el encargado de dar formato, el programador no debe preocuparse por ello, y simplmeente debe utilizar las funciones `toLocale` y derivados.

Comment: @EduenSarceño, en general estoy de acuerdo contigo. Estaría mucho más de acuerdo si existieran la funciones `fromLocaleString(text)` para números y fechas (y quizás booleanos). Por ejemplo en https://codenautas.com/txt-to-sql (que recibe una tabla_de_datos.txt y genera los sql de create table e inserte) podría autodetectar los valores numéricos con mayor precisión. Si los únicos valores que veo son `1.000` y `1,000' ¿cuál es el uno y cuál el mil? Cierto es que la palabra final la tiene el usuario (que puede confirmar su configuración), pero si uno como programador pudiera ayudarlo debería.

Comment: me temo que no se puede hacer nativamente, lo mejor será implementarlo de cero o utilizar una librería de terceros, recomiendo [globalize](https://github.com/globalizejs/globalize)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar la función **[`toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Number/toLocaleString)** para obtener los signos de puntuación acorde al idioma.

Le puedes pasar como parámetro el sistema de numeración que adoptará y los posibles valores son: "arab", "arabext", "bali", "beng", "deva", "fullwide", "gujr", "guru", "hanidec", "khmr", "knda", "laoo", "latn", "limb", "mlym", "mong", "mymr", "orya", "tamldec", "telu", "thai", "tibt" o dejar que el detecte el idioma del sistema (como he hecho en este caso).

Para el caso de las fechas, hay una función similar, **[`toLocaleDateString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)** que te permite obtener la fecha representada según el idioma.

Ejemplo:

```js
var numero = parseFloat(1548789.15).toLocaleString();
console.log("Número: " + numero);

var fecha = new Date();
console.log("Fecha de hoy: " + fecha.toLocaleDateString());
```

Comment: Parece que no fui lo suficientemente explícito. Necesito un método que pueda poner dentro de un programa. Lo agrego en el texto de la pregunta.

Comment: @EmilioPlatzer ¿A que te refieres con que "puedas poner dentro de un programa"?

Comment: ahí puse un ejemplo que se puede poner dentro de un programa (que devuelve los dos valores que necesitaba en un objeto). El problema de ese ejemplo es que no sé si funciona para la mayoría de las localizaciones posibles.

Comment: @EmilioPlatzer Osea, si entiendo bien, lo que quieres es obtener los signos de puntuación de cada región, ¿no?

Comment: lo que quiero son los signos de puntuación que está usando el navegador. Me gustaría que ese método sirva para muchos navegadores en muchas regiones (o en pocas pero saber en cuáles sí o sea qué cosas puedo detectar. Con mi función de ejemplo se podría decir "detecta separador de miles y decimal multicaracter, no detecta signo y falla si el separador de miles es nulo")